# Auxiliary variables for imputation in survey data

Tags: data-imputation, survey-sampling, auxiliary-variable

I have a situation where I have a survey that contains two parts, everyone answers all of the questions on the first part, and a sample (10 percent) of the people are selected to answer some further questions. The 10 percent is selected using a simple random sample. Although everyone is supposed to answer the first part there will be some missing data due to non-response. In order to impute the first part of the questionnaire I will be performing nearest neighbor donor imputation.

My question is: is it alright to use data from the second part of the questionnaire to help impute data for this first part? For example, if  the first part of the questionnaire asked a question on Age (which the respondent did not answer) but the respondent did answer a question about salary in the second part (and gave a positive value) I could assumed that they were of working age and during my imputation of age, I could take this into account.

My fear is that only 10 percent of the population (those that answer the second part) will see the benefit of this during imputation. I am assuming that this will not bias the estimate of Age since the 10 percent is sampled at random, but what if it weren't? What if there was some population that always answered the second part? What does this due to the variance of my estimate?